# do following task after onLocationChanged is called()

Tags: android, locationlistener

I have a class implementing the LocationListener

```
public class GetLocation implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("GetLocation", "Location changed: " + location.getLatitude()
            + ", " + location.getLongitude());

}
```

In my activity,

```
final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    final GetLocation locationListener = new GetLocation();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

     .....  //Check whether the location is changed

    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

    updateGPStoServer();
```

After onLocationChanged() is called once, I want to do a upload task and cancel the listener, so I am asking how can I wait for the onLocationChanged() then do my tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After onLocationChanged() is called once, I want to do a upload task
>   and cancel the listener, so I am asking how can I wait for the
>   onLocationChanged() then do my tasks?

I think you need to move the call to `updateGPStoServer()` into your `Listener.onLocationChanged` method; that would implement the "waiting" that you're looking for. (On a separate note: `updateGPStoServer()` should be implemented to create a background Thread to do the updates to the server. But you knew that, right? :-)

Also, it sounds like you really want to be calling `LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate` instead of `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates`. That would remove the need to call `locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener)`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I am curious about what is the use of looper in requestSingleUpdate()?

Comment: If you pass null for the Looper argument, the callback will be made on the thread where you're making the call. Otherwise, the callback will be made on the thread that the Looper is associated with. (All `Looper` objects are associated with a specific thread.)